# Save Tweets to python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, twitter

I want to analyse twitter data.I have downloaded some tweets and saved them in a .txt file.

When I tried to extract useful information from the tweets data , i was not able to make any progress because for a beginner like me it seems very difficult to extract tweets , location etc.

while googling i found if we convert json into dictionary it would be easy to extract the info.

Now I want to convert my JSON data to python dictionaries. I don't know how to proceed.

Here is the code used to save tweets

```
import tweepy
import json
import jsonpickle

consumer_key = "*********"
consumer_secret = "*******"

access_token = "************"
access_token_secret = "**********"

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


# It make the Tweepy API call auto wait (sleep) when it hits the rate limit  and continue upon expiry of the window. 
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True,  wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

if (not api):
    print ("Can't Authenticate")
    sys.exit(-1)


searchQuery = 'SomeHashtag'
maxTweets = 10000000 # Some arbitrary large number
tweetsPerQry = 100
fName = 'file.txt'

sinceId = None
max_id = "Latest tweet ID"

tweetCount = 0
print("Downloading max {0} tweets".format(maxTweets))
with open(fName, 'a') as f:

    while tweetCount < maxTweets:
        try:
            if (max_id <= 0):
                if (not sinceId):
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, lang ="en", count=tweetsPerQry)

                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, lang ="en", count=tweetsPerQry,
                                        since_id=sinceId)
            else:
                if (not sinceId):
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, lang ="en", count=tweetsPerQry,
                                        max_id=str(max_id - 1))
                else:
                    new_tweets = api.search(q=searchQuery, lang ="en", count=tweetsPerQry,
                                        max_id=str(max_id - 1),
                                        since_id=sinceId)

            if not new_tweets:
                print("No more tweets found")
                break
            for tweet in new_tweets:
                f.write(jsonpickle.encode(tweet._json, unpicklable=False) + '\n')

            tweetCount += len(new_tweets)
            print("Downloaded {0} tweets".format(tweetCount))
            max_id = new_tweets[-1].id
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            # Just exit if any error
            print("some error : " + str(e))
            break

    print ("Downloaded {0} tweets, Saved to {1}".format(tweetCount, fName))
```

Comment: How does your .txt file look like?

Comment: I've edited the grammar of your question. please check that it is clear. Please add the requested information: the contents of the txt file and the enough code so it can be tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can just read your file line by line and unpickle it using [`jsonpickle.decode`](https://jsonpickle.github.io/api.html#jsonpickle.decode) method:

```
tweets = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        tweets.append(jsonpickle.decode(line))
```

And I think you can bypass third-party library at all:

```
import json
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for tweet in new_tweets:
        f.write(json.dumps(tweet) + '\n')

tweets = []
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        tweets.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: when i tried to download tweets with json.dumps() instead of jsonpickle ,in error window i got some tweet data along with the error " is not JSON serializable "